Disable a key in Ubuntu 24.04
So, my laptop delete key is stuck internally. I tried disabling it using xmod -e 'keycode 119 = 0x0000'. But I am still detecting it in xev. Sometime when text editor is open everything gets deleted. I have added the above command in start-up application to no avail.

Find the keycode for your Delete key by running xev | grep --line-buffered keycode . For many keyboards, the Delete key is mapped to keycode 119. The xev | grep --line-buffered keycode command opens a small Event Tester window with a big black square in it. Click
inside the black square and press the Delete key. On my Ubuntu the result of pressing the Delete key was state 0x0, keycode 119 (keysym 0xffff, Delete), same_screen YES, which showed that keycode 119 is mapped to the Delete key on my keyboard.
Use xmodmap -e 'keycode 119 = NoSymbol' to disable the Delete key. Press the Delete key to check if the command worked.

To make this change permanent open the .Xmodmap file for editing in nano text editor.
touch ~/.Xmodmap
nano ~/.Xmodmap

Add the following line, and then save the changes to .Xmodmap using the keyboard shortcuts at the bottom of this answer.
keycode 119 = NoSymbol

Create an .xprofile file if it does not already exist.
touch ~/.xprofile

Open the .xprofile file for editing in nano text editor.
nano ~/.xprofile

Load the change made by disabling the Delete key automatically on login by adding this line to your .xprofile file:
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

The instructions for using nano are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination Ctrl + O and after that press Enter to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination Ctrl + X to exit nano.

This does not work. After doing all of this when I enter xev command I get this:
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x495, subw 0x0, time 13123390, (160,105), root:(210,224),
state 0x4, keycode 119 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False
Also things start to get delete

Don't enter the xev command!!! It takes years to understand the gibberish that xevoutputs!! The command I told you to enter is xev | grep --line-buffered keycode not xev .  xev | grep --line-buffered keycode filters the output to give you only the output you need which is one or two lines similar tostate 0x0, keycode 119 (keysym 0xffff, Delete), same_screen YES, where the keycode indicates what key action is mapped to the key you just pressed.

For many keyboards, the Delete key is mapped to keycode 119.

With  xev | grep --line-buffered keycodeI am getting this: state 0x0, keycode 119 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
When I am in my drive things start to go in trash automatically. On editing text files everything gets deleted. Env though delete key is mapped to NoSymbol

You have a completely standard Delete keycode  (119) the same as mine. I am using a Microsoft keyboard. Your problem is not standard however. Is it a hardware issue or is it a software issue? What happens when you run a live session from the bootable USB Ubuntu installer that you used to install Ubuntu? You could try attaching a different USB keyboard. Maybe your computer would be able to run Windows on it. If so that indicates a software problem with Ubuntu.

I had Windows 11 before ubuntu. I installed KeyTweak software to disable the delete key in windows. That worked like a charm and didn't have any issues in windows. However, in ubuntu I have tried known solutions but nothing seems to work. Maybe I should disable my full keyboard?

It seems like you are on the right track. Please back up any configuration files that need to be changed by making a copy of the old file(s) with the extension .bak appended to the end of its filename before making any changes to it.

Yup this worked fine.
